# Distance Between Parallel Planes

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Over the past few days, I have been learning about the distance between a point and a plane and the distance between two parallel planes. I am currently having some trouble in understanding the latter.

I have been learning from this video here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl6x2u88c1w, as well as others which I have found tougher to understand.

We are given the plane equations:

$2x - 3y + z = 4$

$4x - 6y + 2z = 3$

At around 3:49, the video presenter says that we are going to find a point on one of the planes, and that the way to do this is through setting the $y$ and $z$ coefficients to $0$. The objective is to find the shortest distance between this point and the other plane.

However, the presenter unfortunately doesn't take the time to explain the purpose of setting the $x$ and $y$ coefficients to $0$. Nonetheless, this would turn the first plane equation into:

$2x = 4$

And from here it is easy to see that $x = 2$. Which means that the coordinates of the point on the plane are:

$\{2, 0, 0\}$

At this point; I must ask:

How can we know/guarantee that this point is on the plane? It seems to me that just replacing $x$ and $y$ with $0$ provides no guarantee that this point will indeed lie on the plane. If prospective respondents are able to provide some kind of proof or explanation for how we know this then it would be greatly appreciated.

I do have further questions on this topic, but seeing as though this post is already fairly long, I will save them for a separate post.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your second equation of the plane into the Hessian normalform:
$$\frac{4x-6y+2z-3}{\pm\sqrt{16+36+4}}=0$$
and plug in the point situated on the first plane.

Comment: I have done that and the result is not $0$. $\frac{4(2) - 6(0) + 2(0) - 3}{\sqrt{16 + 36 + 4}} = 0.6681531048$. Have I done something wrong here?

Comment: Why should the result to be zero? You get the distance of the given planes.

Comment: I wouldn't have expected the result to be $0$. But in your answer, you have '$= 0$' after the division operation. Why is that?

Comment: This is the so-called Hessian Normalform, i will give you a link

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesse_normal_form

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I have read the entry and I cannot see an example of the format you just used in there (where the number after the equals sign is not equal to the result of the division operation). $(\vec r - \vec a) ⋅ \vec n = 0$ - this makes sense to me, since the dot product of perpendicular vectors is equal to $0$, $\vec a ⋅ \vec n \geq 0$  - so does this, since the distance cannot be less than $0$.  $\frac{4(0) - 6(0) + 2(0) - 3}{\sqrt{16 + 36 + 4}} = 0$ - but this does not, since the result of the division operation is not equal to the number after the equals sign.

Comment: Ok, take just the absolute values, this gives the searched distance, $$d=\left|\frac{ax_0+by_0+cz_o+d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right|$$

Answer (score 0):

Does point $(2,0,0)$ satisfy the plane equation? By setting $y=0, z=0$ we are essentially finding a point of intersection between the plane and axis $x$. Yes, it's possible that our plane is parallel to axis x but in that case $x$ would not be part of the plane equation. Please note that we set $y=0, z=0$ just to make is easier to find $x$, we can set any two coordinates to any values and that will give us an equation to find the third one.

Comment: So is it the case that as long as the first equation is satisfied (there are obviously numerous values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ that could satisfy this equation), then the point does indeed lie on the plane?

Comment: @RyanWalter: yes, that's the whole point (pardon the pun) of having a plane equation. By fixing two coordinates we just make it easier for ourselves to find the third coordinate of a point that will be on the plane.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't realised that. Thanks a lot for that insight.